# ListView with Alphabet on Android

Tags: android, list, listview, alphabetical

I want to do a listview on android and it contains an alphabet near of the list (like iphone application).

I couldnt find any way to implement an list and having alphabets, when ı click on c letter list scrolling and  start with the c Letter.

Thanks

Comment: You mean like the Contact list ? Or you see all the alphabet on the right and you can click on any letter to go to ?

Comment: I can see the all of the list. List contains restaurant names, but I want to see the alphabet also, when I click the e letter the list scroll and show the restaurant names which starts e letter

Comment: Not sure if this is built into Android. You know you can always type on the keyboard to do a search? Not all phones have a kb but it can help narrow down to what you're looking for in a list view.

Comment: I have One Example it Contains two ListView, one is Hotel Name & Second is Alphabets. if I Click on "d" then only Hotel Name is display, which is Start with "d" letter.

Answer (score 1):

May be `FastScroll` fits to you?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setFastScrollEnabled%28boolean%29

Comment: I dont think that's what she asks

Comment: I try to mean;  http://appsreviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/Cures-A-Z-App-for-iPhone.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by using Database,manage a table to store parsed data and then display data in listview by fetching it database table,
please refer the link for more about database in android
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do the same and i ended up putting a list view and a textview into a frame layout and then using touch positions in conjunction with list.setslection() to focus...worked for me ! more here: [Replication of Apple's Search in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431110/replication-of-apples-search-in-android/7442438#7442438)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Sergey Glotov, regarding Fastscroll, please take a look at sectionIndexer interface.
Maybe these links([eg1](http://www.anddev.org/tutusing_alphabetindexer_for_fastscrolling_listview-t10282.html) and [eg2](http://www.anddev.org/tutalphabetic_fastscroll_listview_-_similar_to_contacts-t10123.html)) will help you.