# Android Listview like iphone contacts list(alphabets in right side of the list)

Tags: android

I am new to android development.
I have been searching for list view similar to contacts list i.e a list with alphabetic indexing panel on the right side.

Thanks.

Comment: May be this can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431110/replication-of-apples-search-in-android/7442438#7442438

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing like that in android you have to create custom view. Try from [iphone-uitable-view-in-android](http://blogingtutorials.blogspot.com/2010/12/iphone-uitable-view-in-android.html)
 and [sideindex-for-android.](http://hello-android.blogspot.com/2010/11/sideindex-for-android.html) I have used code from these two links to create iphone like list with alphabets on side.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable reply, I am using sideindex-for-android, it works fine, but i am not able to download iphone-uitable-view-in-android.

Comment: i think second link will be enough for creating list with alphabets on side. In second link headers for each alphabets are not there in list you can create header for each alphabet using these link http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/ or https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/ListView.

Answer (score 1):

The code in sideindex-for-android is more complex than it needs to be.

I created the LinearLayout as that example did and added TextView instances for the letters. But then I had them clickable.

In my onClick(), I see if it is one of these views and get the text from it.

When I loaded my list, I set up a dictionary in the cursoradapter. The setSelection() method gets the offset from this dictionary.

```
public static final String alphabet = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

public Map<String, Integer> getAlphabetOffsets() {

    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    // First initialize the dictionary with all of the letters of the alphabet.
    //
    for (int idx = 0; idx < alphabet.length(); idx++) {
        String aLetter = alphabet.substring(idx, idx+1);
        map.put(aLetter, -1);
    }

    int numFound = cursor.getCount();

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    // Now go through the products' first initials and, when an initial has not been
    // found, set the offset for that letter.
    //
    for (int idx = 0; idx < numFound; idx++) {

        String productName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.PRODUCTS_NAME_COL));

        String current;

        if (productName == null || productName.equals("")) {
            current = "0";
        } else {
            current = productName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
        }

        // By the way, what do we do if a product name does not start with a letter or number?
        //
        // For now, we will ignore it. We are only putting 0-9 and A-Z into the side index.
        //
        if (map.containsKey(current) && map.get(current) < 0)
            map.put(current, idx);

        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    map.put("0", 0);

    int lastFound = 0;

    /*
    Now we deal with letters in the alphabet for which there are no products.

    We go through the alphabet again. If we do not have an offset for a letter,
    we use the offset for the previous letter.

    For example, say that we do not have products that start with "B" or "D", we
    might see:

            { "9" = 0, "A" = 1, "B" = -1, "C" = 5, "D" = -1, "E" = 10 }

    After this runs, will we have:

            { "9" = 0, "A" = 1, "B" = 1, "C" = 5, "D" = 5, "E" = 10 }

    This is so if we click on B, we see the list starting a "A" and see that
    there are no "B" products.

    */
    for (int idx = 0; idx < alphabet.length(); idx++) {

        String current = alphabet.substring(idx, idx+1);

        if ( map.get(current) < 0 ) {
            map.put(current, lastFound);
        } else {
            lastFound = map.get(current);
        }
        System.out.println("alphabet \"" + current + "\" = " + map.get(current));
    }

    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing like that in android (except samsung's contacts view)

the default in android is using `listview` with fast scroll like the native contact list

Comment: Is there any custom list view like that.

Comment: which one are you talking about?