# How to create a list like iPhone contact List in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am building an application on which what i want a contact list like in iPhone like this:

[image]

a vertical navigation strip with alphabets on right side.

Comment: This is exactly [the tutorial](http://twistbyte.com/tutorial/android-listview-with-fast-scroll-and-section-index) you are looking for.

Comment: The OP wants the list of letters down the side, not just a fast-scroll bar.

Comment: Did you even read what is written on that link? **and create a alphabetical section list that displays the letter as you quickly scroll the list.**

Comment: I read the whole tutorial. It creates the fast-scroll bar, and as you scroll, displays **only** the letter you have scrolled to. Not all 26.

Comment: **Thanks** buddy going through the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a ListView and a custom TextView, both within a FrameLayout or AbsoluteLayout. Your ListView should contain all items as it would, without the alphabet. You can then put the letters `A-Z` and a `#` in your TextView, and make sure it's aligned to the right in the layout.

Once your layout is set up, you have to add some code to the TextView. In a Touch or Click event, record the Y value relative to the top, and determine which letter is being hovered over, then you can determine the scroll position for the ListView.

If this seems like too much work, there exist codes out there for this. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724107/android-listview-like-iphone-contacts-listalphabets-in-right-side-of-the-list) for details.